# how to convert all int to str in a nested dict with json.dumps()?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have, an an input, integers. I build a dict out of them (as values). I then dump it to JSON, to be reused elsewhere.

I ultimately (at the "elsewhere") need to use these integers as strings. I can therefore do the conversion

- upstream (when building the dict)
- or on the receiving side (the "elsewhere").

There will be, no matter the solution, plenty of `str()` all over the code. 
I am looking for a cleaner way to convert all the `int` into `str` in that specific case.

One idea is to [recursively parse the dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756547/903011) once it is built, just before the `json.dumps()`, and make the conversion there.
I am wondering, though, if there is not a way to handle this while dumping the JSON? Possibly with [json.JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)? (which to be frank I do not understand much)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that on the receiving end you are running Python, you could convert the ints to strings upon loading the JSON by using the `parse_int` parameter:

```
import json

test = {'foo':1, 'bar':[2,3]}
json_str = json.dumps(test)
print(json.loads(json_str, parse_int=str))
```

yields

```
{u'foo': '1', u'bar': ['2', '3']}
```

---

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

> `parse_int`, if specified, will be called with the string
>   of every JSON int to be decoded. By default this is equivalent to
>   int(num_str). This can be used to use another datatype or parser
>   for JSON integers (e.g. float).

Comment: Perfect, thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for. I was suspecting that `json` could be capable to do the conversion, what drove me off is (in the docs you quote) "By default this is equivalent to int(num_str).". I read it as being the opposite of what I want to do, now after reading with understanding (and with the help of your code) it is clear.