# How to handle dictionary attributes at arbitrarily nested depths?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm parsing a `json` -> `dict` object that has values nested at arbitrary depths.  For example, the outer level are the fields (the data is from a customer service ticketing system) such as 'name', 'sprint_team', etc...  But then for some fields they have a nested `dict` that will have values like 'id', 'value', etc...

I'm pulling it all down to place in a flat file to then copy over to AWS Redshift, but I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to handle all the different nested levels of values I might need.  I was thinking of using a lookup table such as:

```
lookup = {
'customfield_12700': ('sprint_team', 'name'),
'customfield_13208': ('department', 'sub_department', 'name') 
}
```

where the `value[0]` is always the lookup name, and then there can be n number of extra params that will be my levels of nesting.  The reason I'm using a lookup table in the first place is because Jira uses customfields, and I need to map them to the column names in our cloud database.  For example, on the `sprint_team` field I need the `name` attribute for my flat file, etc...

How could I create a function that will take a dictionary object, and then use the lookup table to return the value I need, regardless of how deeply nested it is?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values

Comment: Recursion was my first thought as well, but I usually shy away from using recursion in code that is going to be used in production.

Comment: If you have a recursive structure that needs to be flattened then there is no reason to shy away from recursive parsing. It's not the best way to achieve your ends, it is **the right way** to meet those ends. Since your question *requires* moving hierarchical data to a standard RDBMs, you should put much thought into properly normalizing your input before stashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

This uses your lookup table idea, and just navigates down through the dicts one level at a time.

```
>>> data = {"foo": {"bar": {"baz": 1}}}
>>> lookup = {
...   'customfield': ("foo", "bar", "baz" )
... }

>>> def nest(data, name):
...   path = lookup[name]
...   d = data
...   for p in path:
...     d = d[p]
...   return d
...
>>> nest(data, 'customfield')
1
```

This can also be done recursively, which should be fine unless your dicts are *very* deeply nested!

```
def nest(data, path):
      if len(path) == 0:
          return data
      else:
          return nest(data[path[0]], path[1:])

def find(data, name):
    return nest(data, lookup[name])

>>>find(data, 'customfield')
1
```

Alternatively, using a funky functional approach:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> def compose(*functions):
...     return reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), functions, lambda x: x)

>>> nest = compose(*[itemgetter(name) for name in reversed(lookup['customfield'])])
>>> nest(data)
1
```

`itemgetter` provides a function that accesses an attribute with the specified name. `compose` composes these functions together to make a single function that extracts the nested data.

You could also pre-generate these functions and store them in `lookup` instead of the paths, so they can be used directly when required.

(We have to define our own `compose` function since Python doesn't have one built-in).