# Check whether a nested dict is False in the leaf nodes in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Let's say I have a nested dict, e.g. the following

```
{'agent1': {'status': True}, 
 'block1': {'status': True, 'number': False, 'usable_by': True, 'location': True, 'skill':
                {'speed': False, 'flexibility': True}}}
```

At the lowest key level (the leaves) of this dict, the values are only boolean (True or False). The input dict can basically have any kind of nested structure with different names as keys and no fixed depth.

How can I check in general, whether there is `False` in a given dict.

Comment: Is the nested dict of fixed depth? If not, are you assuming that all 'leaf' nodes are booleans then?

Comment: no fixed depth, all leaf nodes are booleans. I edited the question with more details

Comment: Do you need to know the key corresponding to a `False` value if one exists?

Comment: Nope, no key necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to traverse the dictionaries, and you want to exit *early*:

```
def any_false_leaf(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return any(any_false_leaf(v) for v in d.values())
    return not d
```

This *recurses* through your dictionaries, and returns `True` if there is a nested false value in the structure. Using the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) guarantees that the result is produced as soon as such a value is found.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'agent1': {'status': True},
...  'block1': {'status': True, 'number': False, 'usable_by': True, 'location': True, 'skill':
...                 {'speed': False, 'flexibility': True}}}
>>> any_false_leaf(d)
True
>>> any_false_leaf({'foo': True})
False
>>> any_false_leaf({'foo': {'bar': True}})
False
>>> any_false_leaf({'foo': {'bar': True, 'spam': False}})
True
```

Answer (score 1):

To traverse the nested dict, you can use recursion. See ([Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values))

```py
def contains_false(d):
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            # recurse into nested-dict
            if contains_false(v):
                return True

        # Check value of leaf-node. Exit early
        # if we find a 'False' value.
        if v is False:
            return True

   # no 'False' values found
   return False

>>> d = {1:True, 2:{1:True, 2:True}, 3:{1:True, 2:True, 3:{1:False}}}
>>> contains_false(d)
True
>>> d[3][3][1] = True
>>> contains_false(d)
False
```

This is assuming that you don't need to know the key(s) to reach the 'False' value.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution can be:

```
d = {'block1': {'status': True, 'usable_by': True, 'skill': {'flexibility': True, 'speed': False}, 'number': False, 'location': True}, 'agent1': {'status': True}}

values = []

def find_false(d):
    for k in d.keys():
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            find_false(d[k])
        else:
            values.append(d[k])

find_false(d)
print(False in values)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your nested dictionary to a `NestedDict`

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

d = {
    'agent1': {
        'status': True
    }, 
    'block1': {
        'status': True, 
        'number': False, 
        'usable_by': True, 
        'location': True, 
        'skill': {'speed': False, 'flexibility': True}
     }
}
nd = NestedDict(d)
```

Then get the answer with a one liner

```
>>> all(nd.values())
False
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`