# Python - getting values from nested dicitonary

Tags: python, dictionary

how do I build a `for loop` in order to print all `float` values in this nested `dictionary`, for any `user`?

```
   plist = {'user1': {u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0}}
```

desired output  = `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`

Comment: the values in the inner dictionary are already floats, what do you need?

Comment: @data_garden: you didn't give us any expected output. Also, how much variation is there in your dictionary structure? Can there be an arbitrary level of nesting?

Comment: @data_garden: also, have you tried anything yourself yet? Did you get stuck anywhere?

Comment: Are there any *other* values in the dictionary that are *not* floats?

Comment: If not, this is as simple as `list(d['playlist'].values())` (where `list()` can be dropped in Python 2).

Comment: I cannot depend on 'playlist' as a constant `key`

Comment: Did you search SO for *nested dictionaries*, I imagine there are many Q&A's here, one may fit your needs.

Comment: @data_garden what *can* you depend on? This question isn't nearly specific enough at this point.

Comment: please refer to edit and see if that clarifies the quesiton

Comment: @data_garden: sorry, it doesn't. Will there always be *one* key, or can there be multiple? What should happen if there are multiple?

Comment: @data_garden: you also didn't answer my question about what other values there might be in the nested dictionary.

Comment: always one `key`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values may provide insight

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters I had tried `[v.values() for v in plist.keys()]`

Comment: @data_garden Is there a need to retrieve all of the values for multiple keys? Either together in one list or as a list of lists?

Comment: if that would provide more versatility to the code, in one list, yes

Comment: @data_garden I've updated my answer with one that supports multiple keys as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [dict.values()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) method that does exactly what you want.

```
a_dict = {'user1': {u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0}}
first_key = list(a_dict.keys())[0]
values = a_dict[first_key].values()
print(list(values))
```

Output

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Edit: And if you want to return one flattened list of all values for all keys as mentioned in the comments on the question, you can do this:

```
a_dict = {
    'user1': {u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 2.0, u'Videotape': 3.0},
    'user2': {u'Foo': 4.0, u'Bar': 5.0},
}
values = []
for k in a_dict.keys():
    for v in a_dict[k].values():
        values.append(v)
print(values)
```

Output

```
[4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

Comment: If something is incorrect about this answer with respect to your question, feel free to add a comment so it can be clarified.

Comment: Im sorry, I haven't downvoted it. but I've edited the question so it must not depend on a specific `string` as the outer `key`

Comment: @data_garden I've updated the answer to pull from the first key in the dictionary per the updated question.  Note that this assumes there is only one key in the dictionary, which I believe is the case from reading your comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.values()` to get your desired behavior.

```
   >>> plist = {'playlist': {u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0}}
    >>> list(plist['playlist'].values())
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    >>>
```