# Iterate through a nested Dictionary and Sub Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**JSON:**

```
data = {"result":[{"name":"Teddy","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}},
           {"name":"Barney","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}]}
```

**Code:**

```
i = 0
j = 0
for p in data['result']:
    print('Name: ' + p['name'])
    for v in p['list']:
        i += 1
        print("{0} : {1}".format(i,v[j]))
        j += 1
```

I am trying to access each value and print them out, but unfortunately, without any success, any help is appreciated.

I have seen: [Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values)

Comment: `i` and `j` don't seem to be related to the data in any way at all.

Comment: Eh, see my JSON, I am (not seen here), but I load this into a dictionary, and then I am trying to iterate over it.

Comment: What does "without any success" mean? Can you post the results? Also, can you specify what the expected output is?

Comment: It means, that I am doing something wrong, for some reason I am unable to access the keys in the list dictionary "0", "1", and "2".

Comment: Note that at the end of your `data`, you need to add another `}` like this `..."2":"56"}}]}`

Comment: Ettanany, why explain?

Comment: Because you did not close curly braces for the second element!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your attempt, seems that what you want to do is the following:

```
data = {"result":[
    {"name":"Teddy","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}},
    {"name":"Barney","list":{"0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"}}]}

for p in data['result']:
    print('Name: ' + p['name'])
    for k, v in p['list'].items():
        print("{0} : {1}".format(k,v))
```

Note that `data` is not a JSON object but a Python dictionary.

**Output:**

```
Name: Teddy
1 : 43
0 : 24
2 : 56
Name: Barney
1 : 43
0 : 24
2 : 56
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @haxxir411 Which version of Python are you using? 2 or 3?

Comment: Where to check?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5

Comment: So you should use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`

Comment: Thx a lot :-) :) :)