# AWS BotoCore Error - An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string

Tags: python, dictionary, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm trying to fill a DynamoDB database with data from an old event store 
made out of a PostgreSQL database. After it ran through a good portion of the db entries, this error was thrown when attempting to call the `put_item` function.

botocore.exceptions.ClientError:-

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string

I decided to rerun the code and see what was happening by dumping out all of the table attributes right before it was inserted.

I can see the only "empty string" is in the `answer_string` attribute of a dictionary, called `details`, see below:-

```
Importing event type 5 completed by user: 1933
1933 5 {'answer': {'difficulty': 1, 'answer_string': ''}, 'card_id': n 
'13448', 'review_id': '153339', 'time_spent': 2431}
62 153339
2017-01-18 00:46:48.373009+00:00 2017-01-18 00:46:48.364217+00:00
```

I'm pretty certain this is what's causing the error to be thrown, as none of the other table attributes are incorrect.

My problem is the `details` dictionary can come from dozens of different locations and each `details` dictionary can have different attributes - the one with the `answer_string` attribute is just one of many possible dictionary configurations. I can't possibly check for all possible configurations of a dictionary and verify that they all don't have empty strings.

Is there a way I can do a one time overall check on a dictionary and see if any one part of it is empty?

Comment: Note that if you try to write an empty string into the dynamodb web page, it lets you. I think this is a bug in boto, not an actual limitation of dynamodb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get a dictionary just containing all keys with empty values, you can simply apply a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to the `details`-dict to get all key-value pairs with empty values. E.g.:

```
empty_values = {key: value for key, value in details.items() if not value}
```

If you instead want to filter out the key-value pairs with empty values, so you're left with a dictionary where all keys have values, simply use the same comprehension without the `not`:

```
details = {key: value for key, value in details.items() if value}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - unfortunately this only works for the outermost key value pairs. It is possible that a key's value is another dictionary, and that dictionary can have empty values as keys. Is there a way to extend this dictionary comprehension to cover a deeper scope?

Comment: If course, e.g. check out the following question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll probably have to write my own helper function to get this done then. I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 5):

Or, if you want replace all empty strings with `None` values:

```
def removeEmptyString(dic):
    for e in dic:
        if isinstance(dic[e], dict):
            dic[e] = removeEmptyString(dic[e])
        if (isinstance(dic[e], str) and dic[e] == ""):
            dic[e] = None
        if isinstance(dic[e], list):
            for entry in dic[e]:
                removeEmptyString(entry)
    return dic

dictionaryWithEmptyStringsReplacedWithNone = removeEmptyString(dicrionaryWithEmptyStrings)
```

It is far from perfect but it works.

Answer (score 3):

@PedoDorf's function worked for me though I had to add a check since sometimes it'd return "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when receiving a string

```
def removeEmptyString(dic):
  if isinstance(dic, str):
    if dic == "":
      return None
    else:
      return dic

  for e in dic:
    if isinstance(dic[e], dict):
      dic[e] = removeEmptyString(dic[e])
    if (isinstance(dic[e], str) and dic[e] == ""):
      dic[e] = None
    if isinstance(dic[e], list):
      for entry in dic[e]:
        removeEmptyString(entry)
  return dic
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to account for nested objects, and clean them as well, give this a try. Requires some recursion:

```
def clean_ddb_data(obj):
    cleaned = {}
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            cleaned[k] = clean_ddb_data(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            if len(v) > 0:
                cleaned[k]=v
        else:
            cleaned[k]=v
    return cleaned
```