# Remove double quotes enclosing numbers using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with the following string:

```
'"name": "Gnosis", \n        "symbol": "GNO", \n        "rank": "99", \n        "price_usd": "175.029", \n        "price_btc": "0.0186887", \n        "24h_volume_usd": "753877.0"'
```

and I have to use `re.sub()` in python to replace only the double quotes (`"`) that are enclosing the numbers, in order to parse it later in JSON. I've tried with some regular expressions, but without success. Here is my best attempt:

```
exp = re.compile(r': (")\D+\.*\D*(")', re.MULTILINE)
response = re.sub(exp, "", string)
```

I've searched a lot for a similar problem, but have not found another similar question.

#### EDIT:

Finally I've used (thanks to [S. Kablar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6101071/s-kablar)):

```
fomatted = re.sub(r'"(-*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"', r"\1", string)
parsed = json.loads(formatted)
```

The problem is that [this endpoint](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/) returns a bad formatted string as JSON.

Other users [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600555/9167585) "Parse the string first with json, and later convert numbers to float" with a for loop and, I think, is a very inneficient way to do it, also, you will be forced to select between int or float type for your response. To get out of doubt, I've wrote [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mondeja/a8215d34ee1c0c850d7b3f64ab6b2260) where I show you the comparations between the different approachs with benchmarking, and for now I'm going to trust in regex in this case.

Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: Where do the double quotes (which you call commas are coming in) - have you tried something adhoc like: `json.loads('{' + yourstring + '}')` - and check that?

Comment: Using regex is not the correct way of doing such things. As stated in the comments to S.Kablar's answer, a string of `"\"43"` will get corrupted by your regular expression replacement. Never use regular expressions on structured data; use the intended parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Regex**: [`"(-?\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/ySz6v5/3) **Substitution**: `\1`

Details:

- `()` Capturing group
- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `?` Matches between zero and one times
- `\1` Group 1.

**Python code**:

```
def remove_quotes(text):
    return re.sub(r"\"(-?\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?)\"", r'\1', text)

remove_quotes('"percent_change_7d": "-23.43"') >> "percent_change_7d": -23.43
```

Comment: this doesn't work for many types of numbers and strings like `"43`.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string first with json, and later convert numbers to floats:

```
string = '{"name": "Gnosis", \n        "symbol": "GNO", \n        "rank": "99", \n        "price_usd": "175.029", \n        "price_btc": "0.0186887", \n        "24h_volume_usd": "753877.0"}'

data = json.loads(string)
response = {}
for key, value in data.items():
    try:
        value = int(value) if value.strip().isdigit() else float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    response[key] = value
```

Comment: This works, and is more maintainable than a regexp (I'm upvoting even if I'm still wary of edge cases :-) ). It can also be adapted to complex JSON values with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values)

Comment: This approach is not working because the json parser process the numbers as strings. To be more precise, the string is part of the response returned by [this endpoint](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker) `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroMondéjar. What makes you think it doesn't work? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @Álvaro Mondéjar: this is the idea behind this: convert the strings to numbers afterwards with python. much more stable than using regex.

Comment: Regex and `json.loads()` is not better? [Show this gist](https://gist.github.com/mondeja/a8215d34ee1c0c850d7b3f64ab6b2260).

Comment: And if you want to conserve ints and floats what? This is not a good idea in this case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroMondéjar: test for int added. Btw. json only knows floats.

Comment: So what? In Python you can decode non floating point numbers as ints. You can see in [`json.JSONDecoder()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders).

Answer (score 1):

You came close. You want to **save** the numbers, and the colon, so you need to put them in parentheses, not the rest. Also, numbers are `\d`, not `\D` (that would be *not*-numbers).

So:

```
exp = re.compile(r'(: *)"(\d+\.?\d*)"', re.MULTILINE)
response = re.sub(exp, "\\1\\2", string)

\d+\.?\d*  means "a number (or more), a point (or not), any numbers"
```

## Border cases

The above doesn't cover ".125", which is **no** numbers, **one** point.

And if you changed to "\d*.?\d*", that would match ".", since it is **any numbers", one point, any numbers".

I think the only practicable way is

```
 (\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)
```

with | meaning "or": so, either a number optionally followed by one point and any digits (this matches "17."), **or** a point followed by at least one digit. Unfortunately, "\d+.?\d+" does not match "5".

Or you specify all three cases:

```
 (\d+|\d+\.?\d+|\.\d+)
```

First integers (\d+), then floating points with or without decimals, then decimal parts alone without leading zeroes.