# Python 3.8: Having difficulty with searching through nested lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am accessing data via an API and I end up with data in nested dictionaries and lists.

I am trying to get a list of the locations by searching for the "unitaryAuthArea" in this nested set of data.

The only result I get is:
Sites is a dictionary.

Python 3.8

```
sites={'Locations': {'Location':[{'elevation': '50.0', 'id': '14', 'latitude': '54.9375', 'longitude': '-2.8092', 'name': 'Carlisle Airport', 'region': 'nw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Cumbria'},{'elevation': '108.0', 'id': '355874', 'latitude': '52.415775', 'longitude': '-4.059387', 'name': 'Penglais School', 'region': 'wl', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Ceredigion'},{'elevation': '75.0', 'id': '3930', 'latitude': '51.55138', 'longitude': '-2.55933', 'name': 'Almondsbury', 'region': 'sw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'South Gloucestershire'},{'elevation': '22.0', 'id': '26', 'latitude': '53.3336', 'longitude': '-2.85', 'name': 'Liverpool John Lennon Airport', 'region': 'nw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Merseyside'}]}}
 
srch='unitaryAuthArea'
 
def nested_extract(nested_sites, key):
    for k, v in nested_sites.items():
        if isinstance(k, dict):
            print('\n K is a dictionary')
            nested_extract(k,key)
        if isinstance(k, list):
            print('\n K is a list')
            if isinstance([0], dict):
                print('\n K is an Inner dictionary')
                nested_extract([0],key)
        if k == key:
            print(v)
         
 
if isinstance(sites, dict):
    print('\n Sites is a dictionary')
    nested_extract(sites,srch)
else:
    print('\n Sites is NOT a dictionary')
```

Many thanks.
Dave

Comment: What do you want to extract? Lat and Long?

Comment: At least, you should check if it's a dictionary or a list, not key but value, I think.

Comment: Your recursion does not run even a second time because `k` is a `string` (with value `"Locations"`). And since it is not equal to `unitaryAuthArea`, it does not print anything in the function. After all, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10756427/4636715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the loop a bit, to check v instead of k. And loop if list.

```
sites={'Locations': {'Location':[{'elevation': '50.0', 'id': '14', 'latitude': '54.9375', 'longitude': '-2.8092', 'name': 'Carlisle Airport', 'region': 'nw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Cumbria'},{'elevation': '108.0', 'id': '355874', 'latitude': '52.415775', 'longitude': '-4.059387', 'name': 'Penglais School', 'region': 'wl', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Ceredigion'},{'elevation': '75.0', 'id': '3930', 'latitude': '51.55138', 'longitude': '-2.55933', 'name': 'Almondsbury', 'region': 'sw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'South Gloucestershire'},{'elevation': '22.0', 'id': '26', 'latitude': '53.3336', 'longitude': '-2.85', 'name': 'Liverpool John Lennon Airport', 'region': 'nw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Merseyside'}]}}

srch='unitaryAuthArea'

def nested_extract(nested_sites, key):
    for k, v in nested_sites.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print('\n V is a dictionary')
            nested_extract(v, key)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            print('\n V is a list')
            for elem in v:
                nested_extract(elem, key)
        if k == key:
            print(v)

if isinstance(sites, dict):
    print('\n Sites is a dictionary')
    nested_extract(sites,srch)
else:
    print('\n Sites is NOT a dictionary')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well as it is not constrained to this specific structure.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for as you are saying that you want to get a list of the locations by searching for the "unitaryAuthArea"? This only works if the structure remains the same. I added a if statement in the list comprehension to make sure you will not get an error in case your keyword "unitaryAuthArea" is not in the dict. Hope it helps you. If you are searching for something else, just give me comment.

```
sites ={'Locations': {'Location' :
    [{'elevation': '50.0', 'id': '14', 'latitude': '54.9375', 'longitude': '-2.8092', 'name': 'Carlisle Airport', 'region': 'nw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Cumbria'}
    ,{'elevation': '108.0', 'id': '355874', 'latitude': '52.415775', 'longitude': '-4.059387', 'name': 'Penglais School', 'region': 'wl', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Ceredigion'}
    ,{'elevation': '75.0', 'id': '3930', 'latitude': '51.55138', 'longitude': '-2.55933', 'name': 'Almondsbury', 'region': 'sw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'South Gloucestershire'}
    ,{'elevation': '22.0', 'id': '26', 'latitude': '53.3336', 'longitude': '-2.85', 'name': 'Liverpool John Lennon Airport', 'region': 'nw', 'unitaryAuthArea': 'Merseyside'}]}}

srch ='unitaryAuthArea'

results = [location['unitaryAuthArea'] for location in sites['Locations']['Location'] if location.get('unitaryAuthArea', False)]

print(results)
#output: ['Cumbria', 'Ceredigion', 'South Gloucestershire', 'Merseyside']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate by value not by key:

```
if isinstance(v, dict):
      print('\n V is a dictionary')
      nested_extract(v, key)
if isinstance(v, list):
      print('\n V is a list')
      if isinstance(v[0], dict):
           print('\n V is an Inner dictionary')
           nested_extract(v[0], key)
```

And then instead of `[0]` iterate by each value of the list:

```
if isinstance(v, dict):
    print('\n V is a dictionary')
    nested_extract(v, key)
if isinstance(v, list):
    print('\n V is a list')
    for x in v:
        if isinstance(x, dict):
            print('\n X is an Inner dictionary')
            nested_extract(x, key)
```