# Printing the output of a decision tree without using Sklearn or PPrint packages

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, decision-tree, binary-decision-diagram

I am trying to print the output of a decision tree in the below format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWFXh.png)

I have my decision tree stored as a nested dictionary. I am trying to use the nested looping for the dictionary but having no result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz078.png)

Please let me know any ideas on how to achieve this??

The output must look something like this

```
|--- XO <= 0.50
|   |--- XM <= 0.50
|   |   |--- XF <= 0.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |--- XF >  0.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |--- XM >  0.50
|   |   |--- XB <= 0.50
|   |   |   |--- XF <= 0.50
|   |   |   |   |--- XG <= 0.50
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |   |   |--- XG >  0.50
|   |   |   |   |   |--- XD <= 0.50
|   |   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |   |   |   |--- XD >  0.50
|   |   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |   |--- XF >  0.50
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |--- XB >  0.50
|   |   |   |--- XI <= 0.50
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |   |--- XI >  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of nested dictionaries you have to loop through, you can use recursion:

```
def dictionary_print(dict_):
    for key, values in dict_.items():
        if isinstance(values, dict): dictionary_print(values)
    else: print(key, ':', values)
```

This code is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values).