# Is there any way to iterate over a nested dictionary in Python without using double for-loops?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, nested-loops

Suppose you have the following nested dictionary:

```py
groceries = {
    'tom': {
        'apples': [1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        'lettuce': [1,0,0,1,1,0,0]
    },
    'andy': {
        'oranges': [1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        'eggplant': [1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
        'lettuce': [0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
     }
}
```

Tom and Andy are professional grocery shoppers and go shopping every day. Each list is a result of how many of each product they purchased a particular day of the week. I would like to generate an output list that provides a sum of products purchased for each day of the week for each shopper. The only way I can think to solve this is to iterate using a nested for loop such as:

```py
for k,v in groceries.items():

    for i in v.items():
```

Is there a way to approach this that doesn't involve using a nested for-loop?

Comment: Maybe you can use recursion. Not sure if that is the answer you are look for.

Comment: For recursion you can check [Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values)

Comment: What keeps you from using double for-loop? It seems to be an appropriate usage.

Comment: However you would try to hide it, you have to iterate on the nested structure, so you will need nested loops.

Comment: Question is WHY would you not want a nested loop here?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't think of it as a nested dictionary, because it's not, in any way, a single object that can provide you with information about the lists. It's a dictionary, and its values happen to be *other* dictionaries that are unrelated to the first dictionary.

Comment: Express the data as nested XML and use xpath?

Comment: Express the data as indented text then use a regexp and Eval?  This answer seems like code golf though.