# Access every key in a nested key

Tags: python

```rb
from collections.abc import Mapping
def access_keys(dic):
    print("Checking keys: ",list(dic.keys()))
    
    if len(list(dic.keys()))==0:
        print("No key found:")
        return 
    
    for key , value in dic.items():
        
        if isinstance(dic.get(key, None), Mapping):
            #print(f"{key}:{value}")
            new_dic = json.dumps(dic.get(key), indent=2)
            print(key,new_dic)
            print(f"{'_'*20}\n{'_'*20}\n")
            return access_keys(dic.get(key, None))
            print(f"key:{key}")
            print(f"value:{value}")
        
        else:
            print("None dic got",f"{key}:{dic[key]}")
        
        print(dic.get(key))
```

I want to access every key in a dic but Recursion is ending after getting an empty list of keys, I m not sure what is missing in this.

Please help me to solve this problem, also descibe me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: You have a return in your for loop so the function ends after the first iteration. Your function doesn't apear to return anything so just removing the `return` should solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)

Comment: Provide an example for `dic`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values

Comment: Thanks 'Roy Cohen' and others, i found the problem in the code, it was just a return statement at the wrong place. Now I have solved the problem thanks to Roy.