# How to find dictionary that contains a key in nested dictionary via recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
dct = {'global': {'bar': {'bar1': {'bar2': {}}, 'b': 1, 'zoo': {}}}}
answers = []
# open dictionary that contains 'arg' among key
def get_d(d, arg):
    for key in d:
        if key == arg:
            return d
        elif isinstance(d[key], dict) and d[key] != {}:
            answers.append(get_d(d[key], arg))

get_d(dct, 'zoo')
print(answers) # [None, {'bar1': {'bar2': {}}, 'b': 1, 'zoo': {}}, None]
```

But I want the function to return only that dict, without using a list.

```
# If you change 'answers.append(get_d(d[key], arg))' 
# on 'return get_d(d[key], arg)' result of call would be None
```

The answer I expect is:

```
# {'bar1': {'bar2': {}}, 'b': 1, 'zoo': {}}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, or perhaps tell your expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values)

Comment: @Sujay Expected output of get_d(dct, 'zoo') is {'bar1': {'bar2': {}}, 'b': 1, 'zoo': {}}. But in summary it returns list with right answer and couple of Nones. If I don't use list to save recursions output, it returns only None but I want that recursion to return only right answer

Comment: Ah, so you would like to get the complete dictionaries below the top level that contain the `arg`. And for the case of multiple matches? Should it return a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @crissal in that post he needs print out value but I trying to figure out how to make a proper return of value

Comment: @Dr.V list there is only for illustrative purpose. By design should be only one match.