# How to iterate through an N-level nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, generator, iterable

I find myself making multilevel dictionaries quite a bit.  I always have to write very verbose code to iterate through all the levels of the dictionaries with a lot of temporary variables.

**Is there a way to generalize this function to iterate through multiple levels instead of hardcoding in and manually specifying how many levels there are?**

```
def iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d, number_of_levels):
    # How to auto-detect number of levels? 
    # number_of_levels = 0
    if number_of_levels == 1:
        for k1, v1 in d.items():
            yield k1, v1
    if number_of_levels == 2:
        for k1, v1 in d.items():
            for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                yield k1, k2, v2
    if number_of_levels == 3:
        for k1, v1 in d.items():
            for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                    yield k1, k2, k3, v3
                    
# Level 1
d_level1 = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level1, number_of_levels=1):
    print(items)
# ('a', 1)
# ('b', 2)
# ('c', 3)

# Level 2
d_level2 = {"group_1":{"a":1}, "group_2":{"b":2,"c":3}}
for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level2, number_of_levels=2):
    print(items)
#('group_1', 'a', 1)
#('group_2', 'b', 2)
#('group_2', 'c', 3)

# Level 3
d_level3 = {"collection_1":d_level2}
for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level3, number_of_levels=3):
    print(items)
# ('collection_1', 'group_1', 'a', 1)
# ('collection_1', 'group_2', 'b', 2)
# ('collection_1', 'group_2', 'c', 3)
```

Comment: This is one of the rare strong-use cases for recursion, since nesting is rarely deep enough to cause stack issues. Have you tried a recursive approach?

Comment: Not off-hand. A typical recipe is to pass the "current level" to the recursive function, then check if that layer is in fact a layer, and if it is, pass each sub-piece to a recursive call, else, operate on that data. That may not translate *directly* to your exact case here, but the answer to iterating recursive structures (which I think nested dictionaries would be considered) is often to use recursion, so that's what I thought of here.

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756547/3000206). Again, not directly related, but that's an often-used pattern that may find relevance in your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out this code

it also supports a combination of levels

```py
from typing import List, Tuple


def iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d: dict):
    dicts_to_iterate: List[Tuple[dict, list]] = [(d, [])]
    '''
    the first item is the dict object and the second object is the prefix keys 
    '''
    while dicts_to_iterate:
        current_dict, suffix = dicts_to_iterate.pop()
        for k, v in current_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                dicts_to_iterate.append((v, suffix + [k]))
            else:
                yield suffix + [k] + [v]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d_level1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
    print(f"test for {d_level1}")
    for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level1):
        print(items)
    d_level2 = {"group_1": {"a": 1}, "group_2": {"b": 2, "c": 3}}
    print(f"test for {d_level2}")
    for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level2):
        print(items)

    d_level3 = {"collection_1": d_level2}
    print(f"test for {d_level3}")
    for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level3):
        print(items)

    d_level123 = {}
    [d_level123.update(i) for i in [d_level1, d_level2, d_level3]]
    print(f"test for {d_level123}")
    for items in iterate_multilevel_dictionary(d_level123):
        print(items)
```

the outputs is:

```
test for {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
['a', 1]
['b', 2]
['c', 3]
test for {'group_1': {'a': 1}, 'group_2': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}
['group_2', 'b', 2]
['group_2', 'c', 3]
['group_1', 'a', 1]
test for {'collection_1': {'group_1': {'a': 1}, 'group_2': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}}
['collection_1', 'group_2', 'b', 2]
['collection_1', 'group_2', 'c', 3]
['collection_1', 'group_1', 'a', 1]
test for {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'group_1': {'a': 1}, 'group_2': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'collection_1': {'group_1': {'a': 1}, 'group_2': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}}
['a', 1]
['b', 2]
['c', 3]
['collection_1', 'group_2', 'b', 2]
['collection_1', 'group_2', 'c', 3]
['collection_1', 'group_1', 'a', 1]
['group_2', 'b', 2]
['group_2', 'c', 3]
['group_1', 'a', 1]
```

using recursion is another approach but I thought writing without recursion is more challenging and more efficient :)

Answer (score 5):

I've written this after I saw @VoNWooDSoN's answer. I turned it into an iterator instead of printing inside the function and a little bit of changes to make it more readable. So see his [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68490869/13944524) here.

```
def flatten(d, base=()):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from flatten(v, base + (k,))
        else:
            yield base + (k, v)
```

1- yielding instead of printing.

2- `isinstance()` instead of `type` so that subclasses of `dict` can also work. You could also use `MutableMapping` from `typing` module instead of `dict` to make it more generic.

3- IMO , getting `(k, v)` pairs from `.items()` is much more readable than `k` and `d[k]`.

### More generic ?

Do you wanna expand this to even more generic which **CAN**(not have to, like the solution in the OP) accept the number of `depths` just in case?

Consider these examples:

```
d_level1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
d_level2 = {"group_1": {"a": 1}, "group_2": {"b": 2, "c": 3}}
d_level3 = {"collection_1": d_level2}

for items in flatten(d_level3):
    print(items)
print('------------------------------')
for items in flatten(d_level3, depth=0):
    print(items)
print('------------------------------')
for items in flatten(d_level3, depth=1):
    print(items)
print('------------------------------')
for items in flatten(d_level3, depth=2):
    print(items)
```

output:

```
('collection_1', 'group_1', 'a', 1)
('collection_1', 'group_2', 'b', 2)
('collection_1', 'group_2', 'c', 3)
------------------------------
('collection_1', {'group_1': {'a': 1}, 'group_2': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}})
------------------------------
('collection_1', 'group_1', {'a': 1})
('collection_1', 'group_2', {'b': 2, 'c': 3})
------------------------------
('collection_1', 'group_1', 'a', 1)
('collection_1', 'group_2', 'b', 2)
('collection_1', 'group_2', 'c', 3)
```

`depth=None` doesn't consider the depth (still works like you want at the first place). But now by specifying depths from `0` to `2` you can see that we are able to iterate how deep we want. here is the code:

```
def flatten(d, base=(), depth=None):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            yield base + (k, v)
        else:
            if depth is None:
                yield from flatten(v, base + (k,))
            else:
                if depth == 0:
                    yield base + (k, v)
                else:
                    yield from flatten(v, base + (k,), depth - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty solution for you:

```
d_level1 = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
d_level2 = {"group_1":{"a":1}, "group_2":{"b":2,"c":3}}
d_level3 = {"collection_1":d_level2}

def flatten(d_in, base=()):
    for k in d_in:
        if type(d_in[k]) == dict:
            flatten(d_in[k], base+(k,))
        else:
            print(base + (k, d_in[k]))

flatten(d_level1)
# ('a', 1)
# ('b', 2)
# ('c', 3)

flatten(d_level2)
#('group_1', 'a', 1)
#('group_2', 'b', 2)
#('group_2', 'c', 3)

flatten(d_level3)
# ('collection_1', 'group_1', 'a', 1)
# ('collection_1', 'group_2', 'b', 2)
# ('collection_1', 'group_2', 'c', 3)
```

Be aware!! Python has a recursion limit of about 1000! So, when using recursion in python think very carefully what you're trying to do and be prepared to catch a RuntimeError if you call a recursive function like this.

EDIT:
With comments I realized that I'd made a mistake where I did not add the key to the level1 dict output and that I was using a mutable structure as a default argument.  I added these and parens in the print statement and reposted.  The output now matches the OP's desired output and uses better and modern python.

Comment: it's better not to set mutable values as the parameter default values, use an empty tuple for the d's default value.

Comment: It doesn't report the keys of the level 1 dictionary because it's a bug.  I'll fix it.  Also, using a mutable collection (a list) as a default parameter is a bad idea.  I'll also fix that.  Standby for an edit.

Answer (score 0):

A linear Solution for identifying depth of a dictionary.

```
d={'a':{1:1,2:2},"b":0,'c':"{}"}
print(d)
s=str(d)

dictionary_stack,dictionary_depth=0,0
def push():
    global dictionary_depth
    global dictionary_stack
    dictionary_stack+=1
    dictionary_depth=max(dictionary_depth,dictionary_stack)

def pop():
    global dictionary_stack
    dictionary_stack-=1

string_safety=False
for c in s:
    if c =="'":
        string_safety=not(string_safety)
    
    if not(string_safety) and c =='{':
        push()
    
    if not(string_safety) and c =='}':
        pop()


print(dictionary_depth)
```

Output:

{'a': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': 0, 'c': '{}'}

2

Answer (score 0):

```
nested_dict = {'A': {'key_B': 'value_B'},
           'B': {'key_C': 'value_C'},
           'C': {'key_C': {'key_D':'value_D'}}
           }


def loop_nested(dictionary: dict):
  for key in dictionary:
  value = dictionary[key]
  print(key)
  if isinstance(value, dict):
    loop_nested(value)
  else:
   print(value)


loop_nested(nested_dict)
```