# How to access values in deeply nested json

Tags: python, json

I'm having a file that is deeply nested and wondering how I can access the values for Product (details, color, size, material).

```
  {
     "article": [

      {
       "product":{
        "details": {
        "color": "blue",
        "size": "small",
        "material": "cotton"
        }
      },
      "availability": "in stock",
      "sku": "2317",
      "cost": "$23"
      },
     {
     "product":{
        "details": {
        "color": "red",
        "size": "large",
        "material": "plastic"
        }
     },
     "availability": "no stock",
     "sku": "4342",
     "cost": "$44"
     }
     ],

   "IDs":[
  {
   "name": "Manager",
   "batchID": 3312312
  }
 ]
}
```

My goal is to iterate over the values for each `product` using python.

Thank you in advance

Comment: ?? You can just put it in a for loop.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: to deep searching in json, you need to iterate it recursively , see this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the list of products

```
products = [ item['product'] for item in data['articles']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```py
mydict =   {
     "article": [

      {
       "product":{
        "details": {
        "color": "blue",
        "size": "small",
        "material": "cotton"
        }
      },
      "availability": "in stock",
      "sku": "2317",
      "cost": "$23"
      },
     {
     "product":{
        "details": {
        "color": "red",
        "size": "large",
        "material": "plastic"
        }
     },
     "availability": "no stock",
     "sku": "4342",
     "cost": "$44"
     }
     ],

   "IDs":[
  {
   "name": "Manager",
   "batchID": 3312312
  }
 ]
}

for item in mydict['article']:
    print(item['product'])
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I've put your JSON into [JSONPath](https://jsonpath.com/), and after small trial and error it is evident that you need this JSONPath to access the fields:

`$.article[*].product.details`

Loop through the array using something like that (sorry, don't have a python env to check properly):

```
import json

json_data= json.dumps("your_json")

items = json.loads(json_data)
for i in range(0, len(items['article'])):
   print items['article'][i]['product']['details']
```