# How to iterate over dictionary while keeping the code clean and easy to read?

Tags: python, loops

Assume that I have data in a json-file that looks like this:

```json
"params" : {
    "main" : { 
        "type_A":[
            [
                {"name" : "param1", "value" : 0.000005, "limits" : [0, 0.1],        "vary" : 1, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.2],   "use_limits": 1},
                {"name" : "param2", "value" : -0.00012, "limits" : [-0.1, 0.1],     "vary" : 1, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.2],   "use_limits": 1}, 
                {"name" : "param3", "value" : 0,        "limits" : [0, 1],          "vary" : 0, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.1],   "use_limits": 0}
            ]
        ]
    },
    "background" : {
        "type_B" : [
            [
                {"name" : "param1",         "value" : 0.0985,   "limits" : [0, 0.1],        "vary" : 0, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.1],   "use_limits": 0}, 
                {"name" : "param2",         "value" : 0.015,    "limits" : [0, 1],          "vary" : 0, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.2],   "use_limits": 0}
            ],
            [
                {"name" : "param1",         "value" : 0.0985,   "limits" : [0, 0.1],        "vary" : 0, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.1],   "use_limits": 0}, 
                {"name" : "param2",         "value" : 0.015,    "limits" : [0, 1],          "vary" : 0, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.2],   "use_limits": 0}
            ]
        ]
    },
    "others" : {
        "type_C" :[
            [
                {   "name" : "0",   "value": 0, "limits" : [-1e20, 1e20],   "vary" : 1, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.1],   "use_limits" : 0    },
                {   "name" : "1",   "value": 0, "limits" : [-1e20, 1e20],   "vary" : 1, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.1],   "use_limits" : 0    },
                {   "name" : "2",   "value": 0, "limits" : [-1e20, 1e20],   "vary" : 1, "deviation" : [0.1, 0.1],   "use_limits" : 0    }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

After loading in the data in Python, I can access it over `data["params"]`, which returns the above data as a dictionary with the 3 keys `main, background` and `others`.

I need to loop over this data regularly. These loops can look as straightforward as

```py
for kind in data["params"]:
    for type_ in data["params"][kind]:
        for idx, line in enumerate(data["params"][kind][type_]):
            for parameter in line:
                f(line[parameter], idx)
```

but they can sometimes also be a bit more involved, e.g.

```py
for kind in data["params"]:
    if kind != "others":
    for type_ in data["params"][kind]:
        some_variable[kind] = {type_: []}
        for k, line in enumerate(data["params"][kind][type_]):
            for parameter in line:
                some_variable[kind][type_][k][parameter] = f(line[parameters])
```

These loops can get pretty messy and hard to read (i.e. understand the logic...), which obviously makes them also hard to maintain. Is there a way to clean this up? Maybe with `itertools` or trying a more modular approach using iterators directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        myprint(v)
    else:
        print(f'{k} {v})
```

You can try something like this, this will keep on iterating it until it sees a nested dict, you might also have to use `json.loads()` maybe not sure

check this thread for more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756547/14047235)